# increment value on Angular directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

Here is my issue, I want to apply a directive with a template to elements on the page with a incremental value on them.

My problem is that my value stays at 0, I tried many answers on stackoverflow but didn't succeeded with them, I'm quite new to angular.

here is my directive:

```
app.directive('loader', function ($window) {

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    controller: function($scope){
        if (!$scope.counter)
            $scope.counter = 0;
        else
            $scope.counter++;
    },
    template: '<div ng-class=\"({ \'display-opacity\' : ready{{counter}} })\" ng-transclude></div>',
};

});
```

as requested, here is my pug template:

```
loader
    | test
loader
    | test
```

Comment: Can you show us your html, where you "call" this directive?

Comment: edited to show the template

Comment: And `loader
    | test` results into what html? (Sorry, I don't know pug). But I think, now I understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: in html it would translate to <loader>test</loader> before the directive does anything

Answer (score 1):

After reading the docs about the `transclude` option, I was going to write something (see below), but after playing around with codepen, I got even more confused. I think, what you are trying to do is rather difficult.

A quick (and maybe dirty) solution would be to use a service for your counter. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxwpxo

```js
app.directive('loader', function(myCounter) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {},
    template: '<div>{{opacity}}</div>',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.opacity = myCounter.get();
    }
  };
});

app.factory('myCounter', function() {
  var counter = 0;
  
  return {
    get: function() {
      return counter++;
    }
  };
});
```

---

Previous thoughts:

> The `transclude` option changes the way scopes are nested. It makes it so that the contents of a transcluded directive have whatever scope is outside the directive, rather than whatever scope is on the inside. In doing so, it gives the contents access to the outside scope.
>
> Note that if the directive did not create its own scope, then `scope` in `scope.name = 'Jeff';` would reference the outside scope and we would see `Jeff` in the output.
>
> https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/docs/guide/directive

I don't know, if have a controller outside your directives where `counter` is defined. If yes, the code in your directive controller won't change the value of `counter` (if I've understood the docs correctly). If no, then each directive will instantiate its own `counter`, and because it hasn't been set yet `if (!$scope.counter)` will always be true. And it's behaving differently if the directive has an isolated scope or not.
I'm getting confused!